# Внутренний отступ DIV css

Tags: html, css

Есть блок div, размером 1024px.
В нем 5 блоков.
Блоки нужно отобразить так, чтобы между ними был внутренний отступ, но по краям (левый, правый) - не было. Т-е граница с блоком родителя была на одном уровне.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y72x6/ так?

Comment: @soledar10, или так http://jsfiddle.net/y72x6/1/ =)

Comment: Все это не то...блоки горизонтальные, между ними внутри нужен отступ.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, чем второй вариант не угодил?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk нарисуйте хоть на бумажке от руки да выложите здесь, а то непонятно что не так. :-)

Comment: Есть блок DIV с фиксированной шириной 1024px. В блоке имеется список UL. Список должен быть выровнен по левому и правому краю родительского div. А отcтeпы должны быть внутри между элементами li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например.

**1.** `text-align: justify;`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

li {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

/* 1. justify */
.justify-list {
  text-align: justify;
}

.justify-list:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
}

.justify-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="justify-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**2.** `display: flex;`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

li {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

/* 2. flex */
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="flex">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[поддержка flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)